# Prove that isometries of $S^2$ preserve internal angles of spherical triangles

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle on $S^2$ with internal angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and opposite side lengths $a, b, c$ respectively. Let $T$ be an isometry of $S^2$

Using the spherical cosine rule, we see that $\cos \alpha = \frac{\cos a - \cos b \cos c}{\sin b \sin c}$ is preserved, which means that if $\alpha'$ is the image of  $\alpha$ under $T$, then $\alpha' = \alpha$ or $\alpha' = 2\pi - \alpha$. I'm struggling to prove that the former is true and not the latter. In other words, I'm struggling to prove that an isometry of $S^2$ doesn't "flip" the triangle inside out so that it looks the same, but its inside has swapped with its outside.

I'm allowed to use spherical trigonometry arguments, coordinate-geometric arguments, synthetic-geometric arguments, as well as e.g. facts about the distance metric on the sphere surface. However the only fact about isometries that I can use is that they preserve lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated argument disallowing Riemannian geometry:**

The issue in this question seems to me to be to be expressible in "synthetic" geometry terms as follows: Given a point $A$ and two short line segments $\gamma,\delta$ intersecting only at a common endpoint coinciding with $A$, and assuming that $\gamma,\delta$ do not form a straight angle at $A$, how do you distinguish the "inner" angle $\angle \gamma\delta$ from the "outer" or "[reflex](https://www.mathsisfun.com/reflex.html)" angle?

Here's a rough idea. By extending $\gamma,\delta$, we may assume that they are each great half-circles, having one common endpoint at $A$ and opposite common endpoint at $A'$ which is antipodal to $A$. So $\gamma \cup \delta$ subdivides $S^2$ into two pieces which I'll call "lunes". Neither of these two lunes is a hemisphere, because we assume that $\gamma,\delta$ do not form a straight angle at $A$. We wish to distinguish one as the "inner lune" and the other as the "outer" or "reflex lune".

I think the idea is exactly one of the two lunes is "convex", and we take one that to be the inner lune. Here we should define a subset $X$ of the sphere to be "convex" if for any pair of non-antipodal points $x,y \in X$, the unique shortest geodesic segment $\overline{xy}$ is also contained in $X$. Convexity is clearly an invariant under isometry.

Let me add that the same method should work in Euclidean geometry, where $\gamma,\delta$ are rays with a common endpoint that do not form a straight angle: the union $\gamma \cup \delta$ subdivides the plane into two pieces, one of which is convex and the other is not.

**Older argument allowing Riemannian geometry:**

Isometries in Riemannian geometry preserve area. The total area of $S^2$ is $4\pi$, the area of the "inside" of the triangle is $<2\pi$, and the area of the outside is $> 2 \pi$. Therefore the isometry must take the inside of the $ABC$ triangle to the inside of the $A'B'C'$ triangle ($A'=T(A)$ etc.).

You can apply this same area argument to a "bigon" (or "lune" in my updated argument above) consisting of a pair of half-great-circles meeting a pair of antipodal points, with the conclusion (expressed colloquially) that an isometry takes the "inside" of an angle to the "inside" of the image angle.

Comment: In this question I subsequently have to prove that the triangle area is preserved, so I can't use this fact

Comment: Given your tags, I wrote my answer with the understanding that one could apply principles of Riemannian geometry, for example area of the triangle is the integral of the area form. Is that not allowed? If not, perhaps you should delete the riemannian-geometry tag.

Comment: Deleted the tag

Comment: At this point I must admit I am struggling to determine what an answerer is or is not allowed to use, when approaching your question. Are you expecting an answer in "synthetic" spherical geometry, similar to "synthetic" planar geometry aka Euclidean geometry? Are you instead working in coordinate geometry? What **are** you assuming? You should explain this issue in more detail by editing the text of your question, otherwise the question is rather unclear.

Comment: added this info